# Have an array that is being filled with user input. Want the calculate button to calculate total even if all spots in the array arent filled

Tags: c#, arrays, foreach, int, windows-phone-7.1

```
    private void Calculate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        int x1 = int.Parse(textBox1.Text);
        int x2 = int.Parse(textBox2.Text);
        int x3 = int.Parse(textBox3.Text);
        int x4 = int.Parse(textBox4.Text);
        int x5 = int.Parse(textBox5.Text);
        int x6 = int.Parse(textBox6.Text);
        int x7 = int.Parse(textBox7.Text);
        int x8 = int.Parse(textBox8.Text);
        int x9 = int.Parse(textBox9.Text);



        int[] totalScore = new int[8];
        totalScore[0] = x1;
        totalScore[1] = x2;
        totalScore[2] = x3;
        totalScore[3] = x4;
        totalScore[4] = x5;
        totalScore[5] = x6;
        totalScore[6] = x7;
        totalScore[7] = x8;
        totalScore[8] = x9;
        int sum = 0;
        foreach(int i in totalScore)
        {
            sum += totalScore[i];
        }

    }
```

I have this in my Windows 7.1 App SDK. What I am doing is creating an golf app. Its supposed to take in the scores that the person gets on each hole, and add it to the array. Then the person can click the calculate button and it will add their score, but I want it to be able to work if not all the spots are filled. It keeps crashing on me if even one spot isnt full.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well you could simply write

```
  int sum = totalScore.Sum();
```

however, the reason of your 'crash' is probably the access to the element with index 8.
Remember that array index goes from zero to the array length - 1
So, if you have 9 input boxes your array declaration should be

```
int[] totalScore = new int[9];

totalScore[0] = x1;
totalScore[1] = x2;
totalScore[2] = x3;
totalScore[3] = x4;
totalScore[4] = x5;
totalScore[5] = x6;
totalScore[6] = x7;
totalScore[7] = x8;
totalScore[8] = x9;
int sum = totalScore.Sum();
```

Of course the conversion from the string contained in the textbox.text to an integer should be verified to avoid invalid inputs. The best approach is through the method Int32.TryParse

```
int tempValue;
if(Int32.TryParse(textBox1.Text,out tempValue)
    totalScore[0] = tempValue;
```

.. and so on for the other textboxes.

Comment: Ok, yeah I did it your way and it worked. The only question I have now, is there a way to store all the values the user enters in these boxes? Because on this page, I also have links to other pages, and if the person wants to go back and add another score in after he left the page, I want the current scores to stay there. Is that possible?

Comment: I don't know how this basic functionality works on Window Phone, perhaps if you ask a new question you will get an immediate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try using Int32.TryParse instead of int.Parse(...) method. This way if the textbox is empty conversion from string to Int will not cause exception;

```
int x1;
Int32.TryParse(textBox1.Text,out x1);

int x2;
Int32.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out x2);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you put your `TextBox`'s in an array first, this becomes a lot simpler:

```
private TextBox[] numberTextBoxes;

// Call this method at some point while setting up your UI
private void Initialize()
{
    this.numberTextBoxes = new TextBox[] 
    {
         textBox1, textBox2, ...
    };
}

private void Calculate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
{ 
    int sum = this.numberTextBoxes.Sum(t => this.GetIntValue(t.Text));
    ...
}

private int GetIntValue(string text)
{
    int value;
    int.TryParse(text, out value);
    return value; // 0 if text is not parseable
}
```

This way, you don't need the `x1`, `x2`, `x3`, ... or `totalScore` variables at all. You can compute the sum in a single line.

Answer (score 0):

0 is the neutral element for adding to numbers. ;)

```
if(button1 == empty)
  x1 = 0
else
  x1 = parse()

if(button2 == empty)
  x2 = 0
else
  x2 = parse()
```

...

Answer (score 0):

Use the TryParse instead.

```
   private void Calculate_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        int x1 = 0;
        int.TryParse(textBox1.Text,out x1);
        int x2 = 0;
        int.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out x2);
        int x3 = 0;
        int.TryParse(textBox3.Text, out x3);
        int x4 = 0;
        int.TryParse(textBox4.Text, out x4);
        int x5 = 0;
        int.TryParse(textBox5.Text, out x5);
        int x6= 0;
        int.TryParse(textBox6.Text, out x6);
        int x7 = 0;
        int.TryParse(textBox7.Text, out x7);
        int x8 = 0;
        int.TryParse(textBox8.Text, out x8);
        int x9 = 0;
        int.TryParse(textBox9.Text, out x9);


        int[] totalScore = new int[8];
        totalScore[0] = x1;
        totalScore[1] = x2;
        totalScore[2] = x3;
        totalScore[3] = x4;
        totalScore[4] = x5;
        totalScore[5] = x6;
        totalScore[6] = x7;
        totalScore[7] = x8;
        totalScore[8] = x9;
        int sum = 0;
        foreach(int i in totalScore)
            {
            sum += totalScore[i];
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: I have it set up like you showed it above, but the only obvious things I added was that i set the TotalBlock.Text = sum.ToString();
But now I am getting a different problem. It is showing a number in my TotalBlock, but its not the actual sum of the numbers.